# How to write subset function for object by logical class in R

Tags: r, subset

I have an object in R include gene_name and their value(TRUE/FALSE) such as below:

```
    TSPAN6           TNMD           DPM1          SCYL3       C1orf112            

     TRUE            FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           TRUE           

     FUCA2            GCLC          NFYA          STPG1          NIPAL3             

      TRUE           FALSE          FALSE          TRUE           FALSE
```

The class of object is "logical". My object name is "rest" and I want to get subset from "rest" include just gene name that their value is TRUE.
I write my code in R language.

Comment: names(which(rest,useNames = TRUE))

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you can do that simply by

```
rest[rest == TRUE]
```

or if you want to know the names:

```
names(rest[rest == TRUE])
```

Comment: You don't even need the logical test, you can just do `names(rest[rest])`

Comment: Ah, the beauty of logical indexing! You are right, indeed.